# Trigger on Account to update Contact

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Account and Contact both have Billing_Address__c field. Contact also have checkbox called active__c. If active__c is true and Account Billing_Address__c is update, then Contact's Billing_Address__c is updated . Here is the trigger. It is working fine. But I want to know if there is any problem or how can I optimize this in the terms of memory?

```
 public static void updateContactBillingAddress(List<Account> lstNew, Map<Id,Account> mapOld){
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account acc : lstNew){
        if(acc.Billing_Address__c != mapOld.get(acc.Id).Billing_Address__c && acc.Billing_Address__c !=null){
            accIds.add(acc.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!accIds.isEmpty()){
        List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>([Select ID,active__c, Account.Billing_Address__c,Billing_Address__c FROM Contact where AccountID IN :accIds]);
        List<Contact> lstUpdateCon = new List<Contact>();
        for(Contact con : lstContact){
            if(con.active__c == true){
                if(con.Billing_Address__c != con.Account.Billing_Address__c){
                    con.Billing_Address__c = con.Account.Billing_Address__c;
                    lstUpdateCon.add(con); 
                  }
             }
            else{
                con.Billing_Address__c =null;
                lstUpdateCon.add(con); 
            }
        }
        if(!lstUpdateCon.isEmpty()){
            update lstUpdateCon;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger on Account to update Contact Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397554/trigger-on-account-to-update-contact-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, it's semantics but i'd return a contact,  1 method, 1 thing. You're processing accounts and updating them, I'd return the `List` of contacts and not update them in the same method.  If you need to `update contacts` down the road you will end up doing unnecessary DML statements, you also don't need to create a `List` just for that loop.

```
public static List<Contact> updateContactBillingAddress(List<Account> lstNew, Map<ID,Account> mapOld)
{
    List<Contact> result = new List<Contact>();

    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Account acc : lstNew)
    {
        if(acc.Billing_Address__c != null && acc.Billing_Address__c != mapOld.get(acc.Id).Billing_Address__c)
        {
            accIds.add(acc.Id);
        }
    }

    if(!accIds.isEmpty())
    {        
        for(Contact con : [Select ID,Active__c, Account.Billing_Address__c,Billing_Address__c FROM Contact where AccountID IN :accIds])
        {
            if(con.Active__c == true){
                if(con.Billing_Address__c != con.Account.Billing_Address__c)
                {
                    con.Billing_Address__c = con.Account.Billing_Address__c;
                    result.add(con); 
                }
             }
            else
            {
                con.Billing_Address__c = null;
                result.add(con); 
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```